# java.awt.color to java.lang.string conversion

Tags: java

I would like to convert java.awt.color object to string.

```
Color c = new Color(255,0,0);
System.out.print(Color.toString);
```

It prints java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]

Now I suppose to parse this string and decode the color name e.g blue etc.

I was thinking is there any other way I can directly convert this Color into String.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I would like to store this color values in database. Should I store it as a String or RGB value?

Comment: *"Should I store it as a String or RGB value?"*  Definitely the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. At least because:

- few rgb combinations have a color name
- java does not hold the color names in all languages it has locale support for

But you can do otherwise. Get the predefined constants in `Color` and check if any of them has the same RGB as the given color. If so - print the name.

As for your added question - store it as RGB value rather than string.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to start with a list of agreed-upon color names, such as [these](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp). Then build a `Map<Color, String>)` from which to get the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods `getRed()`, `getBlue()`, `getGreen()`, and `getAlpha()` to get the color's components instead of parsing the string returned from `toString()`.  You can also compare the color with the static fields in java.awt.Color (using `Equals`.)

Comment: Why get the components? E.g `Color.blue.equals(new Color(0, 0, 255))`.

Comment: I meant, get the color's components instead of parsing the string returned from `java.awt.Color.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML4 basic and extends color keywords. They should be possible to get directly from the rgb values using a table like this: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4