# Set Color of JLabel Using a String

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlabel, foreground

I am working on a Java project. I want for the user to input a color for a Label. I want to do something like this, but with a String.

```
jLabel3.setForeground(Color.blue);
```

Here is what I tried, but didn't work:

```
String a = "blue";
jLabel3.setForeground(Color.a);
```

or:

```
String a = "blue";
jLabel3.setForeground(a);
```

Is there possibly another way to do this with a method? Any help would be great. Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Map<String, Color> colors = new HashMap<String, Color>();

// ...

colors.put("blue", Color.BLUE);
colors.put("red", Color.RED);
colors.put("green", Color.GREEN);
// other colors
```

Then use it like:

```
String a = "blue";
jLabel3.setForeground(colors.get(a.toLowerCase()));
```

---

**EDIT:** Consider a color chooser. See [How to Use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html).

Comment: "-1: Work only for predefined color, not for user defined colors" - Aubin

Comment: +1 for `Map<String, Color>`; the reverse is suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6717956/230513) for arbitrary [named colors](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp). Also consider a [two-way map](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3430170/230513).

Comment: @Legend, he could provide a method for registering user-defined colors -- by putting new values into the map.

Answer (score 4):

Try reflection:

```
Color color;
try {
    Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField("yellow");
    color = (Color)field.get(null);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Besides that you can create a map of colors and their names.

Comment: -1: Work only for predefined color, not for user defined colors, reflection is not designed for this need even if your code sample compile and runs well.

Comment: Eng.Fouad has done for me, nothing to add, it's perfect and upvoted

Comment: Then you have nothing to contribute here. Also, last I checked, his only worked for predefined colors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way but you could do somthing like:

```
If("blue".equals(a)){
    jLabel3.setForeground(Color.blue);
}
```

Comment: And if we have 256 colors, you add 256*3 LOC every where you need a color?

Comment: @Aubin Exactly, it's a very primitive way but it could be effective depending on how many different colors the user is allowed to use.